# wsl command with pipliening

Tags: linux, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to run a linux command on my windows pc using wsl

but i ran into the following Problem, when trying to Pipline inside wsl, Widows tried to pipline:

this worked fine in Powershell:
`wsl -- echo hello`

output: `hello`

here I had the following problem:

input: `wsl -- echo hello | wc`

expected output:      `1       1       6`

but I got:

```
wc : Die Benennung "wc" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren
Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und
wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:18
+ wsl echo hello | wc
+                  ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that Powershell see's the | and tried to interpret it within Powershell as opposed to WSL. YOu need to pass each element of the command as a quoted parameter and so:

```
wsl -- 'echo' '"hello"' '|' 'wc'
```

Comment: You can also save some quotes by using: `wsl -- eval 'echo "hello" | wc'`

Comment: Or better still wsl -- bash -c 'echo hello | wc'

Comment: WSL2 I just escape the pipe, redirect etc  `wsl ls -l /  ^| grep "home"` and `wsl ls -l / ^> /home/mike/dirs.txt`